# Sphinx Service is MISSING in Kaltura?

Tags: linux, search, service, sphinx, kaltura

The base problem is that i can't upload anything in the KMC. Then i found there are many problems in the api v3 log. One of them is "Sphinx". Then when i check the "Sphinx", **there is no "searchd" service running instance on the server**.
When i run:

```
~ # ps aux | grep "searchd"
```

It is showing nothing. **No "searchd" service** of "Sphinx" is running.
Again when i:

```
~ # sh /opt/kaltura/app/scripts/searchd.sh start
```

There is no `search.sh` file to run.
All the files inside that folder are:

```
[root@myserver ~]# ls /opt/kaltura/app/scripts/ -lah
total 100K
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache root 4.0K Jun  7 15:00 .
drwxrwxrwx. 23 apache root 4.0K Jun  7 15:00 ..
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 1.9K Jun  7 15:00 addVirusScanProfile.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 2.9K Jun  7 15:00 analyze_collect_stats.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 1.4K Jun  7 15:00 billing_summary_insert.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  944 Jun  7 15:00 billing_summary_www.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 1.1K Jun  7 15:00 bootstrap.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 1.2K Jun  7 15:00 categoryCount.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 1.9K Jun  7 15:00 clear_cache.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  907 Jun  7 15:00 define.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 5.0K Jun  7 15:00 findEntriesSizes.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  679 Jun  7 15:00 find_unique_visitors.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  322 Jun  7 15:00 flix.watchdog.sh
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  534 Jun  7 15:00 logger.ini
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  902 Jun  7 15:00 makeRemoteStorageDeletable.php
drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache root 4.0K Jun  7 15:00 puser_kuser_deprecation
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 3.4K Jun  7 15:00 serviceBatchMgr.sh
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 2.7K Jun  7 15:00 serviceBatchSingle.sh
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 1.7K Jun  7 15:00 sphinx_watch.sh
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  980 Jun  7 15:00 update_partner_activity.sh
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache root 4.0K Jun  7 15:00 utils
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  979 Jun  7 15:00 uv_summary_insert.php
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root  424 Jun  7 15:00 watch.batchMgr.sh
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root 2.8K Jun  7 15:00 www_logs_insert.sh
```

No `searchd.sh` file. What should i do?

There is COMPLETELY NO SEARCHD running on the server. Seems somethings has done wrongly before.
So should i:

- Install a new dedicated Sphinx instance on the server? (will it work with Kaltura)
- Or is there anyway to add/install the Sphinx only for Kaltura?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit too late, it was replaced with the improved sphinx_watch.sh